# Flutter - CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED

Tags: android, flutter, android-studio, dart

After change minSdkVersion from **16** to **19** on old android devices eg. Android 5.1.1, Android 6 I install app but can't load data from web rest api. On Android 11 all work fine.

I'm change version because some plugin need min sdk 19.

Which android version my app now supports?

```
android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "com.example.test"
            minSdkVersion 19
            targetSdkVersion 30
        }
```

My sdk manager:
[image]

Console log when run app on Android 6 emulator.

```
D/PathProviderPlugin( 4466): Don't use TaskQueues.
I/FLTFireMsgService( 4466): FlutterFirebaseMessagingBackgroundService started!
E/flutter ( 4466): [ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(209)] Unhandled Exception: HandshakeException: Handshake error in client (OS Error: 
E/flutter ( 4466):  CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED: unable to get local issuer certificate(handshake.cc:359))
E/flutter ( 4466): #0      _SecureFilterImpl._handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:104:46)
E/flutter ( 4466): #1      _SecureFilterImpl.handshake (dart:io-patch/secure_socket_patch.dart:147:25)
E/flutter ( 4466): #2      _RawSecureSocket._secureHandshake (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:794:54)
E/flutter ( 4466): #3      _RawSecureSocket._tryFilter (dart:io/secure_socket.dart:924:19)
E/flutter ( 4466): <asynchronous suspension>
E/flutter ( 4466):
```

Comment: just curious, do you see any error or warning log on logcat when you changed the ask to 19?

Answer (score 1):

In main.dart file I'm add:

**import 'dart:io';**

```
class MyHttpOverrides extends HttpOverrides{
  @override
  HttpClient createHttpClient(SecurityContext? context){
    return super.createHttpClient(context)
      ..badCertificateCallback = (X509Certificate cert, String host, int port)=> true;
  }
}


--Add before runApp(MyApp());
HttpOverrides.global = MyHttpOverrides();
runApp(MyApp());
```